# How to calculate variance - covariance matrix of a matrix?

Tags: covariance-matrix

For example, we have an NxP matrix with N rows and P variables. Then we need to calculate a PxP sample covariance matrix. How do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems you're looking for [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance#Calculating_the_sample_covariance). Here's the relevant excerpt:

> The sample covariance of *N* observations of *K* variables is the *K*-by-*K* [matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_%28mathematics%29) $\bar{\bar q}=[[q_{jk}]]$ with the entries
>   $q_{jk}=\frac{1}{N-1}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\left(  x_{ij}-\bar{x}_j \right)  \left( x_{ik}-\bar{x}_k \right)$,
>   which is an estimate of the covariance between 
>   variable $j$ and variable $k$.

All I can think to add is that the diagonal entries $q_{jj}$ are equivalent to the variables' [variances $(s^2)$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Sample_variance).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Nick Stauner, I could say that if you use R you can do

```
cov(yourMatrix)
```